# Stripe card token can't be blank - Stripe & Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe with Devise for my rails app.  When I attempt to sign-up my user and include credit card information, I keep getting the following error: *Stripe card token can't be blank*.  For those that have integrated Stripe with Devise, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here.  Will include some basic code and happy to provide more as need be.  Thank you.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :lastname, :industry, :company, :title, :address, :state, :city, :zip, :stripe_card_token, presence: true
  validates :phone, presence: true, length: { maximum: 11 }
  after_create :create_a_customer

  def create_a_customer
    token = self.stripe_card_token
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :card => token,
      :plan => 2017,
      :email => self.email
    ) 
  end
end
```

**application/.js**

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  user.setupForm()

user =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        user.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, user.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('#stripe_error').show()
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

**App/Views/Devise/Registration/New**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, 'First Name' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname, 'Last Name' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

    .
    .
    .


     <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

      <% if @user.stripe_card_token.present? %>
        Credit Card is on File
      <% else %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
        <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
        <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
        </div>

      <% end %>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Application/Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    user_path(current_user)
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :lastname, :title, :industry, :company, :address, :zip, :phone, :state, :city]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :lastname, :title, :industry, :company, :address, :zip, :phone, :state, :city) }
  end
end
```

**Stripe_Card_Token is Blank Upon Submit**
[image]

Comment: In your Rails server console, can you check if your request has Stripe token in it?

Comment: Hi @Jagjoit, thanks for your response.  The stripe card token is empty when I go to submit the form.  I attached an image above.

Comment: In your handleStripeResponse function can you check if you are getting the ID by console.log?

Comment: Hi Jagjot, thanks for your response.  I'm not exactly sure what you'd like me to do.  if you could clarify or provide some basic instructions, I'd be happy to run the test for you.  Thank you.

Comment: so I learned that my jquery is not loading and I can't figure out why.  First time jquery is not working, checked the gems layout/application, and config/development files.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.